# saving entered String characters into a 2D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I need some help, I do not know where I am getting the error here..
I need to save each character of the entered string in a 2D-Array. I also entered row and column number and the horizontal and vertical orientation. From there I evaluated each character of the string using `charAt` and save it in a specific location in an array based from the row and column number entered..
here's my code..

```
playedword = word.getText().toString();
evalrow = Integer.parseInt(inrow.getText().toString());
evalcolumn = Integer.parseInt(incolumn.getText().toString());
evalorient = inorient.getText().toString();

if(evalorient.equals("H")){
    orientation=0; //horizontal
}
else if(evalorient.equals("V")){
    orentation=1; //vertical
}

if(playedword.length()>0){
    if(vertical == 0){
        for(int u=0; u<playedword.length(); u++){
            arr2[evalrow][evalcolumn+u] = playedword.charAt(u);
        }
    }
    else if(vertical == 1){
        for(int u=0; u<playedword.length(); u++){
            arr2[evalrow+u][evalcolumn] = playedword.charAt(u);
        }
    }
}
```

arr2 is my 2d array with 6x6 dimension.....
I do not know the error here..please help

Comment: http://imgur.com/jacoj

Comment: @kathy Could you please post the error message you get when the program breaks? Should look something like "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tb.py", line 10, in <module>
    a()"

Answer (score 0):

for converting from string to 2D array try this logic

```
char[][] array = new char[5][5];
String str="hello how are you my dear";
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
  str.getChars(i*5, (i*5)+5, array[i], 0);    // str is the 25-char string
}
```